# What are the payouts for each heist in GTA V singleplayer?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I got all the bags in the first heist and netted something like 600k for Michael and 150k for franklin.  I picked an experienced crew so i think they took around 30%, meaning the total payout was probably 1 million or so.

What are the gross payouts for each of the heists before the crew members take their cuts?

I'm curious because i want to know if it's worth leveling up my crew so they take less of a cut, or if i should just stick to the pros and pay the larger cost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The Jewel Store Job**

The maximum take for the mission is $4,946,153 if the player smashes all 20 displays and chooses a good gunman. $2,500,000 will then go to Martin Madrazo while the rest gets split between the crew.

**The Merryweather Heist**

No payoff - Reason is spoiler

**The Paleto Score**

The crew manage to get around $8,016,020 during this heist.

**The Buraeu Raid**

no payoff

**The Big Score**

Choosing the obvious approach will yield around $31,000,000 per character, as long as you choose a good driver to pilot the helicopter, otherwise half the score will be lost. Taking this approach is far more difficult.

Choosing the subtle approach will yield around $24,000,000 per character. It is important to have a good hacker; lesser skilled hackers will cause lag in the traffic lights making this part of the heist more difficult.

**Good Recommendation**

solarosh

On a side note, I recommended only doing the first Lester mission for now. Reason being, these missions biggest payoff is in taking advantage of your advance knowledge of the repercussions these missions have on the stock market. Doing so is some of the best money in the game, and logic dictates that the more cash you have on hand to invest before rigging the market, the higher the dividends you will reap... Remember -- Always Buy low, Sell high

Sources

http://gta.wikia.com/Heists

http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Blitz_Play (solarosh recommendation)

Answer (score 0):

On the jewel store job I would do smart way and have Packie McReary (12%) as gunman, Karim Denz(8%) as driver, and Rickie Lukens(4%).

On the Paleto Score (Make sure u used Packie before) I used Packie.

On the Bureau Raid I chose the roof way and had Norm as a gunman and (Rickie needs experience form the jewel store job) Rickie as hacker and Taliana Martinez(4%) as driver (so she arrives in an ambulance)

On the Big Score I chose the obvious way (200,600,000) Taliana as helicopter driver, Karim as train driver, Norm as first gunman, and Daryl Johns as seconds gunman. I got about 41 million

Answer (score -2):

**1. The Jewel Store Job**

- Michael gets $750k
- Franklin gets 150k
- Trevor is not in the heist

**2. Merryweather Heist**

- You get $20k but then minus $20k

**3. The paleto score**

- Michael gets 460k
- Franklin gets 150k
- and Trevor 150k

**4. The buraeu raid**

- No payout

**5.the big score**

- Each character gets 31960000$